# Delete rows from table using JOIN - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table_A -

```
id  |   name  |  is_active |
----+---------+------------+
1   |  jon    |    1       |
2   |  ham    |    0       |
3   |  gary   |   null     |
```

I have a table_B -

```
id  |   name  |
----+---------+
1   |  jon    |
2   |  ham    |
```

I want to remove rows from table B that have `is_active` value as `0 OR null` in table A. So I'm thinking about an INNER JOIN on `id` column and applying a `WHERE` clause.

```
DELETE ROWS from table_B B
INNER JOIN table_A A ON B.id = A.id
WHERE A.is_active = 0 OR A.is_active IS NULL
```

I don't want any additional columns or changes in table B after the above query. Is this the right way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `JOIN`, use `exists`:

```
DELETE FROM table_B
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM table_A A
                  WHERE A.id = table_B.id AND
                        (A.is_active = 0 OR A.is_active is null)
                 );
```

Comment: are you missing a line from your code? because i don't see the `exists` part

Comment: It should immediately follow WHERE (e.g., DELETE ... WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 ...)

Comment: i'm getting `SQL Error [102] [S0001]: Incorrect syntax near ')'` on the last line for some reason. Using the exact query as above but with `DELETE .. WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1...);`

Answer (score 0):

You need to say which table you want to delete from, use the alias if you have one:

```sql
DELETE B
FROM table_B B
INNER JOIN table_A A ON B.id = A.id
WHERE (A.is_active = 0 OR A.is_active IS NULL);
```